# Factory won't set password and password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

My User.rb has:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
```

My factory_girl for a user is:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|

  u.password "my_password"
  u.password_confirmation "my_password"

end
```

My User.rb sets the encrypted_password field when the object is saved.

It seems when the values that I set in my factory (the passwords), are not being set at all.

In my tests I have to do:

```
it "should ...." do
  user = Factory(:user)

  user.password = "abc123"

end
```

Why would this be the case?

I have the password attribute as both an accessor and accessible.

Is something conflicting?

Comment: Are you using any kind of authentication gem or code?

Comment: nowk nothing that should be conflicting...(its my own custom)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the above, I believe, is that those `attr_accessor` fields are not persisted in the database, so they are 'lost' when declared in `factories.rb`. The solution for that is to set them explicitly when creating a new object from factory:

```
user = Factory(:user, :password => '123')
```

Also see:

- http://groups.google.com/group/factory_girl/browse_thread/thread/4db1151333a96c50